# extract value fom Row in table contain array element

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i have in my row an array 
when 

i go this result

```
{"type":"person1","id":"12"}
```

I want just to get the id as result value 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json_decode:

```
$value = ' {"type":"person1","id":"12"}';

$result = json_decode($value, true);

echo $result['id'];   // 12
```

Comment: thanx too much for ur fast reply . it works

Comment: @achraf-hasairi if its work than mark as accepted the answer by click on the left tick mark. It will help to others

Comment: sory i m newbie  here  Done i clicked on the left tick mark

Answer (score 0):

```
$addedBy = json_decode($row['added_by']);
$id = $addedBy['id'];
```

Comment: thanx too much for ur fast reply . it works